# Python quit with MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos

I upgraded my OS to MacOS Big Sur lately and the Pycharm could not function with my code. The error message indicates that python quit unexpectedly with the current OS. Functions such as matplotlib trigger this problem.

```
Problem details and system configuration

Process:               python3.7 [2347]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python
Identifier:            python3.7
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        pycharm [814]
Responsible:           pycharm [814]
User ID:               504

Date/Time:             2020-11-16 15:37:02.559 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        34EA0CE8-BDD4-CCC6-1DBE-DE5330A5B79D


Time Awake Since Boot: 2000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xffffffff00000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2347]

VM Regions Near 0xffffffff00000008:
--> unused shlib __TEXT      7fffde96f000-7fffe1cf3000 [ 51.5M] r--/r-- SM=COW  system shared lib __TEXT not used by this process
    

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   python                          0x0000000103101293 PyBuffer_Release + 19
1   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff24f74a8d data_release_info + 31
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff24f25f81 data_provider_finalize + 64
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff24eebf8d data_provider_retain_count + 74
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204dadd8 _CFRelease + 474
5   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff24f51cff image_finalize + 103
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204dacf2 _CFRelease + 244
```

Comment: How have you installed this version of Python? `/Users/USER/*/python` seems suspect...

Comment: Can you please provide a short code sample that causes the crash? Does it only crash in PyCharm, or does it also crash when running inside a terminal? If you get an error message there, please provide it.

Comment: Eg. a sample code from matplotlib:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()`

It shows python quit unexpectedly. I have tried test in terminal directly with it, and it shows the same problem, as well as a message `zsh: segmentation fault  python
`

Comment: `python.org` says, under the heading Installers, "3.9.1 is the first version of Python to support macOS 11 Big Sur. With Xcode 11 and later it is now possible to build “Universal 2” binaries which work on Apple Silicon."

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a version problem. I shifted it to python 3.6 and the problem was solved. Maybe python 3.7 and higher could not support these libs.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after Big Sur upgrade. It persists with python 3.6
I found a temporary workaround by replacing the line plt.show() by plt.savefig("filename"). Of course, this is a loss of use comfort.

It was now fully solved by shifting from python 3.6 to 3.9

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem in python2.7.16, I tried to downgrade the matplotlib version to 1.5.3 then this solved the problems.

```
pip install --user matplotlib==1.5.3
```

maybe also try the lower version for Python3?